# Структура проекта PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

Вопрос из 2 частей.

1. Это к какой структуре стремиться при построении проекта (все в контексте обучения, пытаюсь понять как строить проекты).

Мысли такие:

```
    project/
    |app
    ||..
    |core
    ||..
    |public
    ||src
    |||js
    |||css
    ||index.php
    |.htaccess
```

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, замечаниями и опытом.

2. Это то, что папка *public* через нее должно идти взаимодействие с пользователем, соответственно корень проекта - изолирован. Так вот, файл **.htaccess** может в этом помочь. 
   Схема такая, что при переходе на ресурс проекта, файл **.htaccess** отправляет все в public.

Как организовать перенаправление? И как перенаправить доступ к стилям?

Comment: *"Это к какой структуре стремиться при построении проекта "*  --- всё зависит от проекта и от скилов людей, раюботающих с ним.... единого что-то нет. Есть разве что наиболее распространённые (типа фреймворковские), но со временем люди начинают насраивать свои структуры...следуя разным методологиям и практикам

Comment: Это все понятно, вот хотелось бы услышать, какие-то рекомендации, а если с пояснениями, то совсем замечательно)

Comment: Рекомендации какого плана? Отделяйте мух от котлет  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Не плохо!)))) Про котлеты) А со 2 вопросом? Может есть опыт?

Comment: Тут ещё проще... самое стандартное: направить корень сервера на папку public, например в апаче это `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public/"`  и потом в папке public  в .htaccess прописать стандартное  `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]`   каждое правило с новой строки

Comment: По структуре... ну возьмите любой фреймворк...например начните с Yii2 basic и изучите его структуру.. скопируйте и попробуйте.... аналогично посмотрите какой-нибудь Laravel и Symfony и тоже изучите что там и для чего..... самое простое....... ну а потом смотрите всякие модульные монолиты, микросервисы, DDD, связанные контексты, гексогональная архитектура... и  в добивку: Porto

Comment: В целом нормально, только src-то с какого перепугу в паблике? И непонятно, в чем разница между app и src. И core, если уж на то пошло.

Comment: Такая структура поселилась в моей голове после поисках в сети. Ни в коем случае, не претендует на правильность, наоборот за советом сюда и пришёл)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Структура современного проекта в принципе сводится, условно, к четырем каталогам

- `vendor`, в котором лежат используемые проектом готовые модули. То, что сейчас лежит в core, по уму должно идти туда
- `src` или app - собственно РНР файлы проекта
- `config` - конфигурация
- `public` - публичная папка, в которой из РНР файлов только index.php, а остальное - ресурсы, используемые фронтендом: яваскрипт, стили, картинки

Соответственно, .htaccess преренаправляет все запросы к *несуществующим* файлам на index.php. И к стилям, в этом случае, ничего перенаправлять не нужно будет.

Внутри index.php вызывается **роутер**, который на основании описанных в **конфигурации** правил, вызывает тот или иной код из папки src.

Comment: Можете, непосредственно, написать пример .htaccess файла для подобного рода вещей.

Comment: ох, камон. во-первых, .htaccess файла не имеет ни малейшего отношения к подобного рода вещам. Во-вторых, эта .htaccess файла УЖЕ написана миллионы раз. В частности, один из самых популярных ответов на этом сайте по тегу похапе как раз и посвящен написанию этой   .htaccess файлы. И нет ни малейшей причины повторяться

Comment: Дополнил ответ по структуре

Comment: Решений конкретных очень мало или они очень обо всем и сразу. Удобнее информацию понять на примере, который решаешь. Вот у меня такие "загоны" появились и ответа прямого я не нашел, опять же потратил время на понимание этого .htaccess и его регулярных выражений. Затрудняется это все тем, что не видишь отладочной информации. Может (скорее всего так можно) отладку смотреть по поводу работы сервера

Comment: "Мало конкретных решений", серьёзно? Вот это прямо серьёзно сейчас?

Comment: Значит у меня трудности с поиском ответов, поэтому и обратился сюда. Не сочтите за наглость, хотелось тут найти ответ.

Comment: Тыкнете где это решение. Я с удовольствием его попробую применить. А потом уже скажете насколько Вы умнее!

Comment: @ИгорьЮрьевич [так вот же](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1565648/#comment2821523_1565648)  чем не устроило? и ещё по фреймворкам там же написал и подходам........а в целом на текущем сайте есть поиск и можно просто вбить php htaccess ..... да и в поисковике такое прокатит